# Nested Foreach Loops and their order

Tags: c#, loops, foreach, nested

I was wondering if the order in which a nested foreach loop is declared matters in programming? I was running a nested foreach loop and due to some error, the information wasn't processed.

In this instance, I'm trying to access 'sentences' stored in a list known as allSentencesList and replace certain 'words' that are found in those sentences which also exist in a list known as the entityList (XmlNode typed) and then finally adding them to a list known as the processedSentencesList.

```
foreach (string processedSentence in processedSentencesList) //list that needs adding
{
    foreach (XmlNode entity in entityList) //xmlnode list containing two xml tags: text and type 
    {
        foreach (string sentence in allSentencesList) //list containing sentences
        {
            string processedString = sentence.Replace((entity["text"].InnerText), 
                (entity["text"].InnerText + "/" + entity["type"].InnerText)); //replacing the words found in the 'text' tag with the aforementioned new word 
            processedSentencesList.Add(processedString); //adding the new sentence to the new list
        }
    }
}
```

However, the processed sentences with the replaced words are not added to the new list and therefore left me wondering if the order of how a nested foreach loop is declared affects the processes?

Thank you :)

Comment: Is processedSentencesList empty at the beginning?

Comment: Please put more effort into formatting your code before posting. It really isn't that hard to get the indentation right, and it makes it easier for *everyone* to read.

Comment: @matan7890 yes it is sir

Comment: If you use a foreach loop, you enumerate all the elements inside it and loop body is done for each of them. What are you trying to do is to extend this enumeration while iterating over it.... that doesn´t work

Comment: @user3079215 wait for my answer, I'll try to explain your mistake. Also, what is the use of the XmlNodes? Everyone of them is another word?

Comment: @matan7890 basically I'm describing entites such as Bill Gates, Cars, Dodge Charger with (Bill Gates/Person, Dodge Charger/Automobile). So I'm iterating through the sentences to find the word (for eg: Bil Gates) and replace it with (Bill Gates/Person). That's the use :)

Comment: @user3079215 and each node has both text and type right?

Comment: @matan7890 Yes sir! :)

Comment: @user3079215 so I believe that my answer will satisfy you :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume your `processedSentences` collection is empty in the beginning. Therefor, your loops are never executed. Besides that, you should never modify a collection while iterating over it.

The fix should be simple though; do not iterate over processedSentences, but only over entityList:

```
var processedSentencesList = new List<string>();
foreach (XmlNode entity in entityList) //xmlnode list containing two xml tags: text and type 
{
    foreach (string sentence in allSentencesList) //list containing sentences
    {
        string processedString = sentence.Replace((entity["text"].InnerText), 
            (entity["text"].InnerText + "/" + entity["type"].InnerText)); //replacing the words found in the 'text' tag with the aforementioned new word 
        processedSentencesList.Add(processedString); //adding the new sentence to the new list
    }
}
```

Comment: sir this works but it only replaces every sentence with one word from the Entity List. It would serve the purpose if it can replace all the words found in the entity list, not just one. Why do you think that happens?

Comment: @user3079215 Because it is also incorrect, the nested loops are not in the right order...

Answer (score 0):

I think you got the wrong idea of what foreach is doing:

foreach statement takes every object in a list\array\any other group of object and do something for each object.

If I understands correctly, your code starts with an an foreach for an empty list. That means that your code will try to find an object in the list, which of course doesn't exist, and after it "finishes" with all the object (AKA is not doing anything) it will skip all the entire loop.

What you **do** need to do is to iterate on the existing two lists (or whatever) and while iterating add the processedString each time to the list. **Be aware that there are better ways to replace the words than using XmlNodes**, but I'll go with your code:

```
foreach (string sentence in allSentencesList) //for each string in the list do as following:
{
    foreach (XmlNode entity in entityList) //Replace each word in the string:
    {
        string processedString = sentence.Replace((entity["text"].InnerText), 
            (entity["text"].InnerText + "/" + entity["type"].InnerText)); //replacing the words found in the 'text' tag with the aforementioned new word 
        processedSentencesList.Add(processedString); //adding the new sentence to the new list
    }
}
```